# Excel - Sum of successive products in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

Let's assume I have a column with 3 numbers x1, x2 and x3.
How do I write a formula in Excel to get ( x1 * x2 * x3 + x2 * x3 + x3) without creating a new column.

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Sumprod function but didn't work as expected

Comment: show it. 
How are the numbers separated?

Comment: The numbers are in different rows but in the same column. For example A1=2, A2=3, A4=4. In that case the formula should compute 2*3*4+3*4+4 = 40

Answer (score 4):

### Running Product!?

[image]

```
=LET(d,A2:A5,
REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(d),,0),
    LAMBDA(rr,r,rr+PRODUCT(DROP(d,r)))))
```

**Edit**

- Although not as elegant as the first, this one should be more efficient:

```
=LET(d,A2:A5,
    rs,ROWS(d),
REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(rs,,0),
    LAMBDA(rr,r,rr+PRODUCT(INDEX(d,SEQUENCE(rs-r,,r+1))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean that, if the numbers were in `A1:A3`, you'd want a more flexible set-up for calculating:

```
=(A1 * A2 * A3) + (A2 * A3) + A3
```

Or, if that range was extended to `A1:A4`:

```
=(A1 * A2 * A3 * A4) + (A2 * A3 * A4) + (A3 * A4) + A4
```

If those assumptions are correct:

```
=LET(
    ζ, A1:A3,
    ξ, SEQUENCE(ROWS(ζ)),
    SUM(EXP(MMULT(N(ξ <= TRANSPOSE(ξ)), LN(ζ))))
)
```

***Edit**: for older versions of Excel*:

```
=SUM(
    EXP(
        MMULT(
            N(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & ROWS(A1:A3))) <=
                TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & ROWS(A1:A3))))),
            LN(A1:A3)
        )
    )
)
```

which may need to be committed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, or:

```
=SUM(
    SUBTOTAL(6,
        OFFSET(A1,
            ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & ROWS(A1:A3))) - 1,,
            1 + ROWS(A1:A3) - ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & ROWS(A1:A3)))
        )
    )
)
```

which, again, may need to be committed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Comment: Assumptions are correct. Your formula gives me #NAME? though ..

Comment: Please confirm your Excel version then.

Comment: Version 16.65. Thank you for your help Jos

Comment: No worries. Have added a version which should work in all Excel versions, though you may need to commit it with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` in your version.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could also do it by successive division if you had Excel 365:

```
=LET(data,A2:A5,product,PRODUCT(data),SUM(SCAN(product,data,LAMBDA(a,c,QUOTIENT(a,c))))+product-1)
```

In using Quotient, I have assumed that the numbers are integers, but you could just use ordinary division:

```
=LET(data,A2:A5,product,PRODUCT(data),
SUM(SCAN(product,data,LAMBDA(a,c,a/c)))+product-1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following under O365:

```
=LET(A,A1:A3, n,ROWS(A), x,N(SEQUENCE(n)>=SEQUENCE(,n))*A,
 SUM(BYCOL(x, LAMBDA(y, PRODUCT(FILTER(y, y<>0))))))
```

Basically what is does is to build a Lower Unit Matrix (LUM) as follows:
`N(SEQUENCE(n)>=SEQUENCE(,n))`:

```
1   0   0
1   1   0
1   1   1
```

Multiply it by input vector `A`:

```
x1  0   0
x2  x2  0
x3  x3  x3
```

then we apply to each column via `BYCOL` the `PRODUCT` function filtering by non zero values and finally sum the result.

Under non O365 and **if the input array has only positive values**, you can take advantage of the following logarithmic identity:

```
log(x*y) = log(x) + log(y)
```

and apply the inverse operation on both sides:

```
x*y = exp(log(x*y)) = exp(log(x) + log(y))
```

putting in Excel terms:

```
=LET(A,A1:A3, n,ROWS(A), x,N(SEQUENCE(n)>=SEQUENCE(,n)),
 SUM(EXP(MMULT(TOROW(LN(A)), x))))
```

which results in a similar approach to @JosWoolley first formula. Even shorter using Upper Unit Matrix, so we don't need to transpose the input array:

```
=LET(A,A1:A3,n,ROWS(A),x,N(SEQUENCE(n)<=SEQUENCE(,n)),SUM(EXP(MMULT(x,LN(A)))))
```

Here is the output for three rows:
[image: output]